# Will files be better than Database in real time processing and saving?

Tags: database

I am trying to:

- Stream Tweets
- Save Them
- Take the tweets from the file and process it
- Save the above result

I am using CSV files. Should I move to MySQL(or any other) Database?

Comment: If you have a single CSV file which you process as a whole, I doubt you'd benefit from a DBMS. On the other hand, if you're selecting subsets which could benefit from indexing, or joining datasets, or doing complex and/or ad-hoc queries, a DBMS may be valuable.

Comment: @reaanb I have multiple csv files, 8 or 9 right now, with multiple `with open...`